# JavaScript onclick redirect

Tags: javascript, onclick

I have this text field and button here

```
<input name="txtSearch" type="text" id="txtSearch" class="field" />            
<input type="submit" name="btnSearch" value="" id="btnSearch" class="btn" onclick="javascript:SubmitFrm()" />
```

and when the user clicks on the submit button this function is suppose to run

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function SubmitFrm(){
        var Searchtxt = document.getElementById("txtSearch").value();
        window.location = "http://www.example.com/search/?Query=" + Searchtxt;
    }
</script>
```

But nothing happens, what I expecting to happen is when the user clicks on the submit button, take the value from the search text box and redirect the user to the url + the value of the search text box...

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing this fixed my issue

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function SubmitFrm(){
        var Searchtxt = document.getElementById("txtSearch").value;
        window.location = "http://www.mysite.com/search/?Query=" + Searchtxt;
    }
</script>
```

I changed `.value();` to `.value;` taking out the `()`

I did not change anything in my text field or submit button

```
<input name="txtSearch" type="text" id="txtSearch" class="field" />            
<input type="submit" name="btnSearch" value="" id="btnSearch" class="btn" onclick="javascript:SubmitFrm()" />
```

Works like a charm.

Answer (score 26):

There are several issues in your code :

- You are handling the `click` event of a submit button, whose default behavior is to post a request to the server and reload the page. You have to inhibit this behavior by returning `false` from your handler:

  ```
  onclick="SubmitFrm(); return false;"
  ```
- `value` cannot be called because it is a property, not a method:

  ```
  var Searchtxt = document.getElementById("txtSearch").value;
  ```
- The search query you are sending in the query string has to be [encoded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent):

  ```
  window.location = "http://www.mysite.com/search/?Query="
      + encodeURIComponent(Searchtxt);
  ```

Answer (score 4):

Change the onclick from

```
onclick="javascript:SubmitFrm()"
```

to

```
onclick="SubmitFrm()"
```

Answer (score 2):

Just do

```
onclick="SubmitFrm"
```

The `javascript:` prefix is only required for link URLs.

Answer (score 0):

Remove 'javascript:' from your code and it should work.

Do you happen to use FireFox? I have learned from someone else that FireFox no longer accepts the 'javascript:' string. However, for the life of me, I cannot find the original source (though I believe it was somewhere in FF update notes).